# MySql show datatype length

Tags: mysql

So I would like to make a query (MySql) to show the length of the datatype's in the column example:

"query"

result:

id.length = 11,
name.length = 100,
etc, etc

Is this possible? I have tried looking it up, but I couldn't find anything.

EDIT

SHOW COLUMNS FROM int_invoer

give's me the datatype's length, but also it's name so I get

int(11)

is ther a way to remove the int part and only show the 11 part?

Comment: Have you looked at what you can query from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) tables? There's one for the columns. And there's also the [CHAR_LENGTH & LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) string functions if you just want to know how many characters / bytes characters are used in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_SCALE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns       
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = dbname AND TABLE_NAME = tableName;
```

Where `dbname` is your database name and `tableName` your table name.
`CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is the maximum length for strings, `NUMERIC_SCALE`  is the maximum number of digit of a number.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html for more available data in the COLUMNS table

Answer (score 1):

Use
`DESC mytablenamegoeshere`
or
`SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytablenamegoeshere`

For more detail use `SHOW FULL COLUMNS ...`

Those queries will give you the table metadata.

Comment: well yes this give's me the datatype length, but also the type itselve so I get int(11) I want to remove the int part

Comment: Do that in your application program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is LENGTH() function

```
SELECT id, LENGTH(id) AS 'id.length',
       name, LENGTH(name) AS 'name.length'  FROM test
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't anwser my question, it just shows me one's not 11